# "Grouping" dictionary by value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, grouping

I have a dictionary: `Dictionary<int,int>`. I want to get new dictionary where keys of original dictionary represent as `List<int>`. This is what I mean:

```
var prices = new Dictionary<int,int>();
```

The `prices` contain the following data:

```
1   100
2   200
3   100
4   300
```

I want to get the `IList<Dictionary<int,List<int>>>`:

```
int      List<int>
100      1,3
200      2
300      4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
var prices = new Dictionary<int, int>();
prices.Add(1, 100);
prices.Add(2, 200);
prices.Add(3, 100);
prices.Add(4, 300);

Dictionary<int,List<int>> test  = 
                   prices.GroupBy(r=> r.Value)
                  .ToDictionary(t=> t.Key, t=> t.Select(r=> r.Key).ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks, but, values contains all object, I want only keys from original dictionary

Comment: @user1260827, sorry missed one thing, you may try the query now. I just tried it in VS and its working

Comment: can anyone explain what the "ToDictionary" does here?

Comment: @burhan, it creates a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), you can read more about [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [GroupBy](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea).

```
Dictionary<int,List<int>> groups = 
             prices.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(i => i.Key).ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my reply. When the dictionaries get large, you will likely find the GroupBy() extension methods less efficient than you would like, as they provide many guarantees that you don't need, such as retaining order.

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions 
{
    public static IDictionary<TValue,List<TKey>> Reverse<TKey,TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey,TValue> src) 
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<TValue,List<TKey>>();

        foreach (var pair in src) 
        {
            List<TKey> keyList;

            if (!result.TryGetValue(pair.Value, out keyList)) 
            {
                keyList = new List<TKey>();
                result[pair.Value] = keyList;
            }

            keyList.Add(pair.Key);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And an example to use in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var prices = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    prices.Add(1, 100);
    prices.Add(2, 200);
    prices.Add(3, 100);
    prices.Add(4, 300);

    // Dump method is provided by LinqPad.
    prices.Reverse().Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy` followed by [the `Func<TSource, TKey>, Func<TSource, TElement>` overload of `Enumerable.ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx):

```
var d = prices.GroupBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lookup instead.

```
var prices = new Dictionary<int, int> { {1, 100}, { 2, 200 }, { 3, 100 }, { 4, 300 } };
ILookup<int, int> groups = prices.ToLookup(x => x.Value, y => y.Key);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In particular case, when we use the .NET framework 2.0, we can do as follows:

```
var prices = new Dictionary<int, int>();
prices.Add(1, 100);
prices.Add(2, 200);
prices.Add(3, 100);
prices.Add(4, 300);

Dictionary<int, List<int>> grouping = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

var enumerator = prices.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var pair = enumerator.Current;
    if (!grouping.ContainsKey(pair.Value))
        grouping[pair.Value] = new List<int>();
    grouping[pair.Value].Add(pair.Key);
}
```