# “Grouping” dictionary by value of class property

Tags: c#, linq

I have similar request like in below link

["Grouping" dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410590/grouping-dictionary-by-value)

But I want to group based on property of the class.

```
public class myClass1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string networkId { get; set; }
}
```

In below example I want a group of networkId

```
        var obj1 = new myClass1() { id = 11, networkId = "asdf1" };
        var obj2 = new myClass1() { id = 22, networkId = "asdf2" };
        var obj3 = new myClass1() { id = 33, networkId = "asdf3" };
        var obj4 = new myClass1() { id = 44, networkId = "asdf1" };
        var obj5 = new myClass1() { id = 55, networkId = "asdf2" };
        var obj6 = new myClass1() { id = 66, networkId = "asdf1" };
        var obj7 = new myClass1() { id = 77, networkId = "asdf1" };

        var classDictionary = new Dictionary<int, myClass1>();
        classDictionary.Add(1, obj1);
        classDictionary.Add(2, obj2);
        classDictionary.Add(3, obj3);
        classDictionary.Add(4, obj4);
        classDictionary.Add(5, obj5);
        classDictionary.Add(6, obj6);
        classDictionary.Add(7, obj7);

        Dictionary<myClass1, List<int>> test2 =
                           classDictionary.GroupBy(r => r.Value.networkId)
                          //.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Select(r => r.Value).ToList());
```

So that the result would be like, a dictionary with key value as per below

```
"asdf1" -> List of obj1, obj4, obj6, obj7
"asdf2" -> List of obj2, obj5
"asdf3" -> List of obj3
```

Any help?

Comment: Does this not work? `.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Select(r => r.Value).ToList());`

Comment: Nope, some compilation error

Comment: Oh, it should be `var test2 = ` (or `Dictionary<string, List<myClass1>> test2 =`), since you want a list of `myClass1`, not `int`. Also, in the future, please include error messages, not just that it's a compilation error - that doesn't help very much :)

Comment: yeah, I should include it from the start. Looking at answer below, if I just make it to var test2 like you mentioned, this question wont pop up. Thanks for the help! I should just do that from the beginning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close.  You simply need to update the target dictionary structure to the following:

```
Dictionary<string, List<myClass1>> test2 = classDictionary
    .GroupBy(r => r.Value.networkId)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Select(r => r.Value).ToList());
```

This creates the following output:

[image]

It is worth noting that this is an excellent use case for `var` instead of explicitly naming the type, since it will determine your output type for you. This is often helpful when trying to determine what the end type will be.